# Revert datetime format, from short to long

Tags: flutter, dart, web, intl

Tried searching around couldn't really find anything. Was hoping to find a way to revert the datetime format.

So I start off with: 4-11-22 and I want to change to Friday, 12 November 2022.

Using the intl package

Comment: What do you mean "...to be in fu"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Then, you can do as follows:

```dart
  String myDate = '4-11-22'; // input date
  String pattern = 'dd-MM-yy'; // define parse pattern for the input date
  DateTime date = DateFormat(pattern).parse(myDate); // parse the input date

  String newPattern = 'EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy'; // define new pattern
  String formattedDate = DateFormat(newPattern).format(date); // reformat
  print(formattedDate); // result: Friday, 04 November 2022
```

Try on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/ab74fa13639b8238589b0b3110d677c8)

For more formatting possibilities, go to the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

```dart
 final oldDateDateTime = DateFormat('dd-MM-yy').parse('4-11-22');
 final newDateString = DateFormat('EEEE, d MMMM y', 'en_US').format(oldDateDateTime);

 print(oldDateDateTime.toString());
 print(newDateString);
```

**Output:**

2022-11-04 00:00:00.000

Friday, 4 November 2022

More in: https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows

```
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy');
    final String formatted = formatter.format(DateTime.now());
```

Then you use the `formatted`